# SQL Command to replace embedded spaces with another character

Tags: sql

I have a relational database with several fixed length character fields. I need to permanently replace all the embedded spaces with another character like `-` so `JOHN DOE`  would become `JOHN-DOE` and `ITSY BISTSY SPIDER` would become `ITSY-BISTSY-SPIDER`. I can search before hand to make sure there are no strings that would conflict. I just need to be able to print the requested files with no embedded spaces. I would do the replacement in the C code but I want to make sure that there is never a future case where there is a `JANE DOE` and `JANE-DOE` in the DB.

By the way I have already made sure that there are no strings with more than one consecutive embedded space or leading spaces only trailing spaces to fill the fixed length fields.

*Edit*: thanks for all the help!

It looks like when I cut & pasted my question from Word to StackOverflow the trailing spaces got lost so the meaning my question was lost a bit.

I need to replace only the embedded spaces not the trailing spaces!

Note: I am using middle dot to stand in for spaces that don't show well.

Using:

```
SELECT REPLACE(operator_name, ' ', '-') FROM operator_info ;
```

the string `JOHN·DOE············` became `JOHN-DOE------------`.

I need `JOHN-DOE············`.

I am thinking I need to use aliasing and the `TRIM` command but not sure how.

Comment: Which database system are you using, MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: Despite saying _permanently_ in your question, please note that if you want the change to be reversible at any point, you should choose a character that does not already exist in the fields.  Otherwise you risk losing information.  e.g., if you use the `-` a name like **Jean-Paul Sartre** will become **Jean-Paul-Sartre**, and if you attempt to reverse it, you will get **Jean Paul Sartre** which may be undesirable.

Answer (score 8):

With whatever REPLACE function is built into your particular database.

MySQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Oracle:
http://psoug.org/reference/translate_replace.html

SQLServer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

---

Edits below based on your comment.

I've done this in SQLServer syntax so please modify the example as needed. The first example really breaks down what's going on and the second one bunches it all into a single ugly query :D

**@output** in this case contains your final value.

```
DECLARE @input     VARCHAR (100) = ' some test    ';

DECLARE @trimmed   VARCHAR (100);
DECLARE @replaced  VARCHAR (100);
DECLARE @output    VARCHAR (100);

-- Get just the inner text without the preceding / trailing spaces.
SET @trimmed = LTRIM (RTRIM (@input));

-- Replace the spaces *inside* the trimmed text with a dash.
SET @replaced = REPLACE (@trimmed, ' ', '-');

-- Take the original text and replace the trimmed version (with the inner spaces) with the dash version.
SET @output = REPLACE (@input, @trimmed, @replaced);

-- Show each step of the process!
SELECT @input AS INPUT,
       @trimmed AS TRIMMED,
       @replaced AS REPLACED,
       @output AS OUTPUT;
```

**And as a SELECT statement.**

```
DECLARE @inputTable TABLE (Value VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @inputTable (Value)
VALUES (' some test    '), 
       ('   another test          ');

SELECT REPLACE (Value,
                LTRIM (RTRIM (Value)),
                REPLACE (LTRIM (RTRIM (Value)), ' ', '-'))
  FROM @inputTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!
I am going to use middle dots to better explain my request
I need to replace only the embedded spaces not the trailing spaces!
Using SELECT REPLACE(operator_name, ' ', '-') FROM operator_info ; the string “JOHN•DOE••••••‘
became ‘JOHN-DOE------------‘ I need ‘JOHN-DOE••••••'

Comment: @user1221579 I've included a simple example that you should be able to expand to your needed. Please accept solution if you find this helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MSSQL:

```
SELECT REPLACE(field_name,' ','-');
```

**Edit:** After the requirement about skipping the trailing spaces.
You can try this one-liner:

```
SELECT REPLACE(RTRIM(@name), ' ', '-') + SUBSTRING(@name, LEN(RTRIM(@name)) + 1, LEN(@NAME))
```

However I would recommend that you put it into a user defined function instead.

Comment: They exact same function is used for MySQL

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!
I am going to use middle dots to better explain my request
I need to replace only the embedded spaces not the trailing spaces!
Using SELECT REPLACE(operator_name, ' ', '-') FROM operator_info ; the string “JOHN•DOE••••••‘
became ‘JOHN-DOE------------‘ I need ‘JOHN-DOE••••••'

Answer (score 1):

assuming SQL Server:

```
update TABLE set column = replace (column, ' ','-')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(field_name,' ','-');
```

**Edit:** After the requirement about skipping the trailing spaces. You can try this one-liner:

```
SELECT REPLACE(RTRIM(@name), ' ', '-') + SUBSTRING(@name, LEN(RTRIM(@name)) + 1;
```